# MySQL Workbench Error 1064 when creating table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to use MySQL Workbench 8.0.3 with MariaDB but I get the following error:

```
Executing:

CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`customer` (

  `ID` INT UNIQUE UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

  `Email` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL,

  `Street` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci' NOT NULL,

  `City` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci' NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`));


ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that     
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `Email` VARC' at line 2
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `mydb`.`customer` (
  `ID` INT UNIQUE UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' NOT NULL,
  `Street` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci' NOT NULL,
  `City` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_czech_ci' NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))


Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
```

The code you see above has been generated using the "Create Table" Workbench feature.

Comment: PK is by default Unique; it does not make sense to define unique constraint on a already defined primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using int(10) instead of int

```
ID INT(10)
```

not

```
ID INT
```

Answer (score 1):

`UNSIGNED` and `INT` go together, so this works:

```
`ID` INT  UNSIGNED UNIQUE NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

This is shorter:

```
`ID` INT  UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
```

A primary key is already non-`NULL` and `unique`.  There is no need to declare those properties twice.